# Is there a way to debug tensorflow java execute ?

Tags: java, debugging, tensorflow

I would like to load 'saved_model.pb' which is generated using python from java and run prediction.

In case of python, I can debug tensorflow run as describing 
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/debug/examples/debug_mnist.py

But when I use java, load 'saved_model.pb' and run prediction, than how can I debug it ?

Answer (score 1):

TensorFlow debugger (tfdbg) is a specialized debugger for TensorFlow.

For more info visit [Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/programmers_guide/debugger)